# How represent this query with Cypher in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm having some problems for solving a query in my Neo4j DB. My DB stores info about users, songs and albums. A user can buy songs and albums and he can follow other users too.

I start from "Lisa" user. I want to find users who bought albums with same style than albums bought by Lisa but they aren't followed by Lisa (they would be recommended users for Lisa to follow them).

I think that query would be similar to this but I can't find the correct sintax to represent it.

```
    MATCH (me:User)-[:BOUGHT]->(a:Album)
    MATCH (other:User)-[:BOUGHT]->(a2:Album)
    WHERE NOT (me)-[:FOLLOWS]->(other) AND me.username="Lisa" 
    AND other.username <> "Lisa" AND a.style=a2.style
    RETURN other.username
```

Any help?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: One thing you might consider, style might work well if modeled as its own node label, that can let you apply multiple styles to albums, and let you take advantage of graph traversal when finding albums of the same style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query works fine with this dataset. I might be misunderstanding something - can you further specify the problem?

```
CREATE
  (u1:User {username: "Lisa"}),
  (u2:User {username: "Louis"}),
  (a1:Album {style: "rock"}),
  (a2:Album {style: "rock"}),
  (u1)-[:BOUGHT]->(a1),
  (u2)-[:BOUGHT]->(a2)
```

I added some cosmetic touches to your query:

```
MATCH (me:User {username: "Lisa"})-[:BOUGHT]->(a1:Album)
MATCH (other:User)-[:BOUGHT]->(a2:Album)
WHERE NOT (me)-[:FOLLOWS]->(other)
  AND other.username <> "Lisa"
  AND a1.style=a2.style
RETURN other.username
```

The result is:

```
╒══════════════╕
│other.username│
╞══════════════╡
│Louis         │
└──────────────┘
```

Comment: Just to note, it's more efficient to use `AND other <> me`, as that avoid unnecessary property comparisons.

Comment: I made a rookie error. The "style" field did not load well on the albums and my query didn't return results. Thanks for the answers and tips. I will consider to model the style as its own node label :)